# How to add caption with the tables r package?

Tags: r, format, latex

Using the iris data, we make a table with the `tables` package:

```
library(tables)
table <- tabular( (Sepal.Length+Sepal.Width) ~
           Format(format(digits=2))*(mean + sd), data=iris )
```

With the `Hmisc` package, we would add the caption with the `latex` function like this:

```
latex(table, caption="My table")
```

But that does not work with the `tables` package, because it defines an S3 method, `latex.tabular`.

So I have tried this, following an example in the [package vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tables/tables.pdf):

```
latex(table, options=list(toprule="\\caption{My table}"))
```

But it does not work, it says that caption is outside float. How can I correctly add caption with the `latex.tabular` function from the `tables` package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out one way to do it and it is actually pretty easy: you just have to embed the `tables` package result inside the latex code.

Below one example with `knitr`, the `<< >>=` is the `r` chunk code.

```
\begin{table}
\caption{My awesome table from tables package}
\begin{center}

<<cool multilevel table, results='asis', echo=FALSE>>=
latex(table)
@

\end{center}
\label{tab:mytable}
\end{table}
```

This generated this awesome table, now with title (in portuguese):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this to help late to help other people looking for help with this. I have been working to understand the tables package recently. The workflow I use is to export the table to a .tex file then pull those into my document which I compile with TexStudio. The solution above wont work with this workflow, so I am providing one which will, it will produce a caption below the table:

```r
latex(table, , options=list(bottomrule = "\\bottomrule\\\\
                                             \\caption{My table}")
```

This will produce one above:

```r
latex(table, , options=list(bottomrule = "\\caption{My table}\\\\
                                             \\toprule")
```

Answer (score 0):

The tables package now has a function `latexTable()`, when used with a latex.tabular object, can add caption and labels. See the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tables/vignettes/tables.pdf)